# Nginx Explode string?

Tags: string, nginx, header

Given the following header value:
`my_cool_header_000`
and sometimes
`my_cool_000`

How can I always drop the last `_000` and save it as a variable in nginx for logs usage?

In PHP I would explode by `_` and drop the last array element, how can I achieve that in nginx?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to use [map](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html) like this:

```
map $my_cool_var $http_my_cool_header {
  ~(.*)_000 $1;
  default   "";
}
```

So when you will use the variable `$my_cool_var` nginx will try to read variable `$http_my_cool_header` which is HTTP header `My-Cool-header`, match it to regular expression and extract some value from it.